# Facebook (#200) User cannot access this application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are working in php facebook project , we post datas from mobile app using open graph apis.
first we are testing in demo site and create an app for the demo site using the demo site urls and added objects for the app. after migrate to live server , we changed the fb app site url to live one but now while post anything from mobile app it throws " (#200) User cannot access this application " error.

can anyone please help on this .

thanks

Comment: Have you forgotten to take the app out of Sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0):

Please check app_id you have used while initializing javascript sdk or while initializing feed dialogue.